# Is there a way to add multiple headers when using Feign Client

Tags: java, spring-cloud-feign, openfeign

I have a Feign client to access to an createUser endpoint that requires two headers: username and password.  I know how to add one header, but how do I add two headers to the request?

```
@FeignClient(name = "client", url = "https://abc.abc.com/user/", configuration = FeignClientConfig.class)
public interface MyFeignClient {

@Headers("username_header: {username}")  // how do I add "password" here.
@PostMapping(value = "v1/users")
void createUser((@Param("username") String username, User userRequest);
```

}

**Update**:  Now based on the answer below, I changed the interface body to:

```
@Headers({"username_header: {username}", "password_header: {password}"}) 
@PostMapping(value = "v1/users")
void createUser(@Param("username") String username, 
                @Param("password") String password,
                User userRequest);
```

And the code that calls it is:

```
feignClient.createUser("me", "123", userObj);
```

Then I am getting an error:

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean,
 nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method has too many Body parameters: 
 feignClient.createUser(java.lang.String,java.lang.String, User)
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it may be late but I am hopping to help others.

What has worked for me:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@PostMapping(path = "${service-uri}", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    String callService(@RequestBody MyBodyClass body, @RequestParam Integer param01, @RequestParam String param02, @RequestHeader Map<String, String> headerMap);
```

The solution proposed with @HeaderMap doesn't work, apparently because this class is from *feign* package (import feign.HeaderMap).

Answer (score 0):

Headers accepts String[] for value ... So

```
    @Headers({ "username: {username}", "password: {password}" })
```

Should do the trick

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and I added `password` to the createUser method signature, but I got an error saying "Method has too many Body parameters:"

Comment: can you post that code @jlp? As the headers and body parameters are different ...

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> @RequestLine("POST /v1/users")
> @Body("{userBody}")
> Response createUser(@HeaderMap Map headerMap, @Param(value = "userBody") String userBody);
> ```

Updated

```
@RequestLine("POST /v1/users") 
Response createUser(String userBody, @HeaderMap Map headerMap);
```

Comment: Not for me: IllegalStateException: Method has too many Body parameters :-(

Comment: As per the Documentation
...
   @RequestLine("GET /servers/{serverId}")
   void get(@Param("serverId") String serverId, @HeaderMap Map );
...


Could you try as mentioned below??

`@RequestLine("POST /v1/users")
Response createUser(String userBody, @HeaderMap Map headerMap);`